# Jquery Draggable Problem in IE7

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-7, jquery-ui-draggable

I am using jquery draggable and it works fine in chrome and firefox. But in IE7, the draggable item and the mouse cursor don't match. I have uploaded a picture here :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdZu5.png
the picture of egg with a red border is been dragged and my cursor is where the blue pointer is pointing !

Comment: pls provide the source code, most propably it is not a jquery issue but just css related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  `position:relative` to your CSS class. Might sound far fetched but I had a similar bug and this fixed it.

Comment: Thanx. I will give it a try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try snapping to a parent container and setting a grid as well.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#snap-to

So in the draggable example on the jquery ui site you could do the following

```
$( "#draggable5" ).draggable({ snap: ".ui-widget-header", grid: [ 80, 80 ] });
```